# Show for any natural $n>1, n^3+1$ is not prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show for any natural $n>1, n^3+1$ is not prime.

$n^3+1= (n + 1)(n^2 - n + 1)$

Case 1.
For some values of $n>1, n+1$ is prime but for those values $n^2-n+1= n(n-1)+1$ is a positive number, hence the resulting number is not prime, as when $n+1$ is prime, $n$ definitely is not.

Case 2: If $n(n-1)+1$ is prime, then $n(n-1)$ is not prime. But, can say only that $n+1$ is a positive number, without being sure of it being prime or not.
Hence, product is not prime.

Comment: Why do you need cases? It's enough that $n+1 \gt 1$ and $n^2-n+1 \gt1$, so $n^3+1$ is the product of two integers, each of them $\ge 2$.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks for that.